# Кнопка назад на посещённую страницу

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть каталог, необходимо при переходе пользователем на детальную карточку товара из этого каталога, реализовать кнопку назад т.е после нажатия на которую пользователь попадает на просмотренную ранее страницу.

Проблема могла бы решится методом `windows.history.back()`, но в каталоге может присутствовать пагинация, которой может воспользоваться пользователь и нам необходимо его перекидывать на ту страницу, которую он выбрал. Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: то-есть если пользователь был на `/about/` , а потом зашел в каталог и перешел на 2-3-4-5 страницу, то потом при нажатии на кнопку должен попасть на `about`?

Comment: нет, только на страницу каталога т.е. пользователь походил по страницам 2,3,...,5 каталога перешёл на любой конкретный товар, нажал кнопку назад и попал в то мето, где был до этого в каталоге

Comment: Ну а кто сказал что `windows.history.back()` не поможет? для него без разницы там навигация или нет

Comment: перед тем как создавать вопрос я попробывал данный метод и он работает только для тех случаев, когда нет пагинации

Comment: А `window.history.go(-1);` не поможет?

Comment: Puvv это эквивалент записи windows.history.back()

Comment: @Puvvl проблема в том, что переходов то по навигации постраничной может быть 20-40, и даже из `window.history.length` вы только будете знать общее количество, но до того могли и быть адекватные переходы.

Comment: Я не профессионал конечно же но может тогда `localStorage.setItem('url', window.locations.href);` поможет?